# How to model a very large world in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, multi-agent

I need to create a very large grid of patches to have GIS information of a very large network (such as a city-wide network). My question is how to get NetLogo to model such a world? When I set the max-pxcor and max-pycor to large numbers, it stop working. I need a world of for example size 50000 * 50000.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig , which says in part: “The NetLogo engine has no fixed limits on size...”

It's highly unlikely that you'll be able to fit a 50,000 x 50,000 world, in your computer though — that's 2.5 billion patches. Memory usage in NetLogo is proportional to the number of agents, and patches are agents too.

You might take Stephin Guerin's advice at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Re-Rumors-of-Relogo-tp4869241p4869247.html on how to avoid needing an enormous patch grid when modeling transportation networks.