# Designing a Computer for Spatially-Explicit Modeling in NetLogo

Tags: hardware, spatial, netlogo, explicit, agent-based-modeling

I have done various searches and have yet to find a forum or article that discusses how to approach building a modeling computer for use with NetLogo. I was hoping to start such a discussion, and since the memory usage of NetLogo is proportional to the size of the world and number of simulations run in parallel with BehaviorSpace, it seems reasonable that a formula exists relating sufficient hardware to NetLogo demands.

As an example, I am planning to run a metapopulation model in a landscape approximately 12km x 12km, corresponding to a NetLogo world of 12,000x12,000 at a pixel size of 1, for a 1-meter resolution (relevant for the animal's movement behavior). An earlier post described a large world ([How to model a very large world in NetLogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356911/how-to-model-a-very-large-world-in-netlogo)), and provided a discussion for potential ways to reduce needing large worlds (http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Re-Rumors-of-Relogo-td4869241.html#a4869247). Another post described a world of 3147x5141 and was using a Linux computer with 64GB of RAM (http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Java-OutofMemory-errors-for-large-NetLogo-worlds-suggestions-requested-td5002799.html). Clearly, the capability of computers to run large NetLogo worlds is becoming increasingly important.

Presumably, the "best" solution for researchers at universities with access to Windows-based machines would be to run 16GB to 64GB of RAM with a six- or eight-core processor such as the Intel Xeon capable of hyperthreading for running multiple simulations in parallel with BehaviorSpace. As an example, I used SELES (Fall & Fall 2001) on a machine with a 6-core Xeon processor with hyperthreading enabled and 8GB of RAM to run 12,000 replicates of a model with a 1-meter resolution raster map of 1580x1580. This used the computer to its full capacity and it took about a month to run the simulations.

So - if I were to run 12,000 replicates of a 12,000x12,000 world in NetLogo, what would be the "best" option for a computer? Without reaching for the latest and greatest processing power out there, I would presume the most fiscally-reasonable option to be a server board with dual Xeon processors (likely 8-core Ivy bridge) with 64GB of RAM. Would this be a sufficient design, or are there alternatives that are cheaper (or not) for modeling at this scale? And additionally, do there exist "guidelines" of processor/RAM combinations to cope with the increasing demand of NetLogo on memory as the size of worlds and the number of parallel simulations increase?

Comment: This may get closed for not fitting the Stack Overflow format. If so, try https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/info

Comment: I think this question will get closed as it violates "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  I'd recommend heading over to the user forum as recommended above