# How many agents can NetLogo supports in a model?

Tags: netlogo

Suppose in a model the NetLogo world is 160 X 101. So, In such a world how many stationary agents and moving agents can possibly be created. Can this world will able to support 100000 moving agents (no die) or possible support by NetLogo to moving agents in a single model.

Comment: Surely you can experiment to find out?

Comment: Yes that's obvious, but I asked if there is some restriction with the features of NetLogo or past experience that will help more to experiment myself. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No formal restrictions, just performance and resources. See [How to model a very large world in NetLogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356911/how-to-model-a-very-large-world-in-netlogo) I have personally modelled with 50,000 agents and it's still reasonable speed. However, get your model working with a MUCH smaller size before expanding as it will slow down.